Is it possible to retrieve "favourite" questions?
If I put a star on a question, could I retrieve it easily?

This is the same on all sites, so the https://meta.stackexchange.com site should have the answer to that, e.g. here. Or even more on topic: this one.


Click on your user icon (Note: Make sure you do so on the main site, and not here on meta)
On the "Activity" page (should be the default page), click on the section labeled "Favorites"


It's located next to "Summary", "Answers", "Questions", etc



